# How to solve system of implications and linear inequalities?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, logic

I have the following system of, erm, implications - what would be the best way to go about solving this system? I would like to solve for $w,x,y,z,\lambda$ in terms of $a,b,c,d,e,f$

$w > 0 => 0.5w + ax + (1-d)y + fz = \lambda$

$w = 0 => 0.5w + ax + (1-d)y + fz < \lambda$

$x > 0 => (1-a)w + 0.5x + ey + bz = \lambda$

$x = 0 => (1-a)w + 0.5x + ey + bz < \lambda$

$y > 0 => dw + (1-e)x + 0.5y + (1-c)z = \lambda$

$y = 0 => dw + (1-e)x + 0.5y + (1-c)z < \lambda$

$z > 0 => (1-f)w + (1-b)x + cy + 0.5z = \lambda$

$z = 0 => (1-f)w + (1-b)x + cy + 0.5z < \lambda$

$w + x + y + z = 1$

$w \ge 0, x \ge 0, y \ge 0, z \ge 0$

Sorry for just dumping a whole system, but I have no idea how to go about this with the implications there!

Comment: Have you tried setting three of the variables $w,x,y,z$ equal to $0$ and seeing what you can conclude from there? That's probably how I'd start.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It lead me to create the approach of subset enumeration - basically setting the subsets of {w,x,y,z} (it was found that lambda has to be 0.5) equal to 0 in all combinations. This yeilds a O($2^n$) approach so I would like to know if there's a more efficient method!

Comment: I'm afraid I won't be able to help you much with that, but I'm glad I could do something! I'd recommend that you edit the body of the post to show the work you've done so far, and to ask about efficiency.